# Passing which link was clicked to another page

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm using autocomplete searchbar which returns lets say 2 results. I make results as links (not sure if this is right, lead me on right path if not) and I need pass to nolasam_rec.php which link was clicked.

```
$query = "SELECT title FROM user_rec WHERE title LIKE '%" . $name . "%'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
            if (!$result) {
                die ("DB query nedarbojas");
            }

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){


 echo '<a href=nolasam_rec.php>' . $row['title'] . "</br>" . "</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a primary key in your `user_rec` table, say, `user_rec_id`, you can pass it like this:

```
echo '<a href="nolasam_rec.php?id='.$row['user_rec_id'].'">' . $row['title'] . "</a><br />";
```

If all your titles are unique, you can also do this:

```
echo '<a href="nolasam_rec.php?title='.urlencode($row['title']).'">' . $row['title'] . "</br>" . "</a>";
```

In your `nolasam_rec.php`, you can access this through `$_GET`:

```
$id = $_GET['id']; // or $_GET['title'];
// then select the record appropriately from the database:
// SELECT * FROM user_rec WHERE user_rec_id=... OR
// SELECT * FROM user_rec WHERE title=...
```

### NOTE: Please read about [SQL Injections](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). This is not only good practice, this is *essential* practice for your database's security.

### Please also note:

1. `<br />` is a [singleton HTML tag](http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/qt/html-void-elements.htm). This means it has to be written that way, with the slash at the end.
2. It's better to put the `<br />` tag after the closing `</a>` tag
3. The `urlencode()` function was used to pass the title. [This function is convenient when encoding a string to be used in a query part of a URL, as a convenient way to pass variables to the next page.](http://php.net/urlencode)

Comment: You should also consider using a nounce to prevent Alice sending a one of your ?id=1337 links to Bob, making it count again when Bob clicks it. Or you could simply check the HTTP referer to make sure the user came from the correct site.

Comment: Thank you, this works great! And yes im aware of injections, ill work on that.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can pass the value to the next page

```
echo '<a href="nolasam_rec.php?title='.$row['title'].'">'.$row['title'].'</a>';
```

AND in the  page i.e. `nolasam_rec.php` you can use `$_GET["title"]` to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

Store the link in the $_SESSION array which you can then access later http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php